# Hide youtube location using Google API in 2023

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I want to hide YouTube channel location for now as a new YouTuber. By mistake I select the location and now option for hide. I saw some video they use this URL:
(https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/update)

This code:

```json
{
  "id": "YOUR_CHANNEL_ID",
  "brandingSettings": {
    "channel": {
      "description": "This is a short description.",
      "defaultLanguage": "en"
    }
  }
}
```

but it show me this error:

> This error may be due to using an insufficient credential type. Try using OAuth 2.0.

What should I do now? Is there any easy way to do it?

Please help me.